# How do I change the brightness in iOS 7?

Tags: ios

I used to be able to double the home button and swipe right to change the brightness. How do I change the brightness in iOS 7 without going to the Settings app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open Control Center, then slide the brightness slider.

Control Center is enabled by default, but can be enabled/disabled through Settings > Control Center.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ask Siri to change the brightness and you can get to the control straight away.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the brightness from the new Control Center, which you access by swiping up from the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swipe up from the bottom to bring up the Control Center.  The top slider will let you change the brightness:

[image]